# ApplicationLog_CL in Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I use Log Analaytics Workspace in order to add logs from my application and use kusto query as follows:

```
ApplicationLog_CL
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

What does this ApplicationLog_CL indicate? Is there a way to add another log type?

Answer (score 0):

1. The 'ApplicationLog_CL' is a reference to the Table in Log Analytics you are querying with KQL.
2. The postfix of '_CL' indicates that it's a Custom Table and will most likely also have the type of 'Custom Table' if you look in the Log Analytics Workspace under Tables.

When trying to create a custom table in LAW through e.g. Bicep or the Azure CLI and you do not add the postfix '_CL' to the table, the creation of the table fails.

It specifies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/table?view=azure-cli-latest) that the table needs to postfixed with '_CL'.

If creating the table through the Azure Portal, Azure will postfix the table with '_CL' automatically.